# java System.nanoTime is really slow. Is it possible to implement a high performance java profiler?

Tags: java

I did a test and found the overhead of a function call to System.nanoTime() is at least 500 ns on my machine.

Seemed that it is very hard to have a high performance java profiler.
For enterprise software, suppose a function takes about 350 seconds and has 12,500,000,000 times of method calls. Therefore, the number of calls to System.nanoTime() is:
12,500,000,000 * 2 = 25,000,000,000 (one for start timestamp, one for end timestamp)
And the overhead of System.nanoTime in total is:
500 ns * 25,000,000,000 = 500 * 25000 s = 12500000s.

Note: all data from real case.

Any better way to acquire the timestamp?

Comment: @willpowerforever: which OS? If you're profiling on a Linux development server if may be possible to modify the underlying timer that Linux is using for gettimeofday() when System.nanoTime() is called. There are several reasons to allow a 'pluggable timer source': at one point the Linux kernel devs noticed (in 2006?) that TSC was broken, then more recent CPUs came with an HPET (high precision timer) offering consistent readings (and maybe faster?) across cores etc. In any case: the time taken by System.nanotime depends on the underlying hardware and how the OS is configured.

Answer (score 20):

I've spent 10 years working on commercial Java performance profilers, for use in both development and production.

The short answer is - yes, you're right.  You can't pull that off.  And even if you could, putting anything but trivial instrumentation into a method that is called so frequently can:

- Change the way the JIT treats the code, thus
- skewing your performance numbers in hard to predict (but generally not useful, from a performance tuning standpoint) ways.

  (and lets not get started on how making a system call in what is basically a tight assembly loop after the JIT is done with it affects all the fancy optimizations the CPU might otherwise be able to do in terms of prefetches, causing an otherwise unnecessary context switch and flushing your L1 cache, etc, etc)

It's OK to instrument slow (or maybe 'infrequently called' would be better?) methods.  You can get away with instrumenting, for example, a lot of the JDBC API to catch database issues.

For actual performance tuning of actual Java code (as opposed to stuff Java calls into, like the network, filesystem, database, ...), instrumentation just isn't really the way to go.  You get more understandable results, but no-one has done line-level instrumentation for performance tuning for probably 7 years now - same reasons.

Instead, commercial profilers use "sampling" technology - they periodically take a stack trace.  JVMTI has some nice calls that make it pretty cheap to do so every few ms.  Then you assume all the time between stack traces was spent on the new stack (which, obviously, isn't true, but statistically, it produces accurate results over a not-stupidly-short measurement period) - and you've got yourself some actionable performance numbers without crazy overhead or any kind of observer effect.

Answer (score 5):

A practical suggestion: Instead of putting the call to System.nanoTime() inside the method, put it outside the loop that calls this method.

However, there is a deeper point here: you are saying that you have a method(s) that is called many times and that adding two System.nanoTimes() calls to this method makes it incredibly slow. From the data that you provided your method is 35,000 times faster than a couple of Systme.nanoTime() calls (12500000s/350s = ~35,000).

This is a pretty fast method. It runs in less than a Nano. I don't think you'll be able to make it any faster. The only performance gains that are waiting for you are those that are based on reducing the number of times this method is called (and not by making the individual method faster).

Is it possible that the data is not accurate?

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you using? Windows, Linux or Solaris? Single or multiple CPU?

System.nanoTime() is just about the lowest-overhead you're going to get. Its speed depends on what OS you're running:

On Windows it calls QueryPerformanceCounter(), on Linux it uses gettimeofday(), and on Solaris it uses gethrtime().

The fastest of these is probably the Solaris gethrtime() - it doesn't have the overheard of a regular OS system call. Even so, it is reckoned to take "a few hundred nanoseconds" on a 300Mhz UltraSPARC box. So 500ns sounds about the right range. You might get faster timings using DTrace, but that's not something I've used.

Sadly, using profiling tools incurs an overhead. But do you really need to run through 12.5 BILLION method call invocations (according to your numbers) to profile your code?

Comment: The concern about nanoTime() is not totally unfounded; it takes about 1500 ns on my fast, modern linux machine.

Comment: @caerphilly: (and Kevin Bourrillion)... I'm pretty sure the source (ie the timer) that Linux uses for *gettimeofday()* is configurable (eg good old PIC or the newest HPET timers etc.) and that there are at least three completely different timer that can be used.  Maybe trying with another source for *gettimeofday()* could help take the 1500 ns down to something more usable (it would be very unlikely all the timers have all the exact same overhead)?  [I'm willing to bet one of my finger that it's at least configurable when you compile a Linux kernel].

Answer (score 1):

If you want profiling, use a profiler, which will hook into the JVM quasi-magically using JVMTI, without needing to jam nanoTime() calls into code.

If you want microbenchmarking, just loop many many times so that when you divide the result by that number, the nanoTime() overhead all but disappears.

Answer (score 0):

> And the overhead of System.nanoTime in total is: 500 ns * 25,000,000,000 = 500 * 25000 s = 12500000s.

By my arithmetic:

```
500 nS * 25,000,000,000 =  12500 S.
```

Because:

```
(500 * 10^-9) * (25 * 10^9) = 500 * 25
```

Comment: Maybe this should have been a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long total = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        long timeNano1 = System.nanoTime();     
        long timeNano2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("timeNano2 - timeNano1 = " + (timeNano2 -timeNano1)); 
        
        total += timeNano2 -timeNano1; 
    }
    
    double avarage = (double)total/1000;
    System.out.println("=================== average = "+ avarage);

}
```

**the results:**

min(timeNano2 - timeNano1) = 0ns

max(timeNano2 - timeNano1) = 249800ns =~ 0.25ms < 1ms

average = 227.3 ns