# in multi threaded code does System.nanoTime() produces small inaccuracy

Tags: java, multithreading, time

in multi-threaded code does System.nanoTime() produces small inaccuracy  whenever the threads are rescheduled?
 and if yes does this error accumulates and is this also true in single-threaded code?

for example when threads start executing it get the time using System.nanoTime() at the beginning and then just before exiting from thread block it records the time using same System.nanoTime()

Comment: Be aware that most computers have only soft-time since any hardware TrueTime solution is costly. And soft-time is accurate only up to probably 1ms depending on the hardware, OS and the programming language. Refer to this docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime() it says that it's behavior is not guaranteed

Comment: Check this out for TrueTime stuff: http://www.symmetricom.com/

Comment: How do you measure that inaccuracy? Do you have a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "small inaccuracy"? Although `System.nanoTime()` gives you nanosecond resolution, there's no guarantee as to the accuracy of the elapsed time that it measures. As far as I know, calling `System.nanoTime()` won't disrupt thread scheduling; there's a small cost of the method call and execution, but that's it. (Of course, doing lots of those calls will accumulate significant CPU time if you do enough of them.)

Comment: 500ns or 1500ns is not a small cost for each System.nanoTime(), i didn't do these test myself but you can find it here , i was just wondering  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476203/java-system-nanotime-is-really-slow-is-it-possible-to-implement-a-high-performa)

Comment: @waheebyaqub - If 1500 ns is a significant fraction of the time you are measuring, then the accuracy of the measurement is likely to be a bigger source of error. Also, variations in system load, the occasional pauses for the garbage collector, and other vagaries of the execution environment are going to introduce significantly more variation than 1500 ns. Like the most up-voted answer in your link points out, the proper approach to instrumenting tight loops is statistical sampling. It averages out lots of errors and reduces the impact of the instrumentation itself in the results.